# How to write easily datas in an empty plist file

Tags: objective-c, ios6, plist

I would like to write/delete **datas.plist** programmatically.

I have a view that contains several buttons that are differentiated by their **tags**.

I want each time a button is pressed :

- write a new item in a dictionnary in **datas.plist**
- each item will contain the **tag id** of the button pressed and other datas

And how in another view, delete the item in the same way.

I use this code to read in datas.plist :

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary;

NSString *plistfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" offType:@"plist"];
[myDictionary writeToFile:@"Data" atomically:YES];
NSDictionnary *dict = [NSDictionnary dictionnaryWithContentOfFile:plistFile];

NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Events"]);
```

Comment: Please note that the chances for good answers are better if you copy/paste your *actual code* (`[NSDictionnary dictionnaryWithContentOfFile:...]` ?)

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [861 other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=write+to+plist+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is trying to write inside the application bundle. This technique is highly discouraged: as far as I know, doing this might break the bundle signature.

Assuming that you have some valid reason to do that, there are other errors in your code. I will try to fix them but, please, keep in mind that you might have to think again your algorithm.

```
[myDictionary writeToFile:plistFile atomically:YES];
```

I'm assuming this was a distraction error: you were trying to write myDictionary to a pre-defined path (most likely not really existing).

The next part of the code is particularly confusing. I will try to answer to the main question.

You can add an entry to the NSDictionary by using:

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
```

and them remove it by using:

```
- (void)removeObjectForKey:(id)aKey
```

So, for example, you can use the following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:<filePath>];
[myDictionary setValue:@"SomeValues" forKey:@"DesiredKey"];
[myDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"DesiredKey"];
```

The code above loads a plist from , then adds to it "SomeValues" as the object for key @"DesiredKey". Then, the last instruction removes the object (in this case, "SomeValues") just added.

Comment: Ok, forget about [myDictionary writeToFile:plistFile atomically:YES]; I understood my error, so now I would like to add/remove an entry into the datas.plist file
How can I use exactly your 2 methods to do that ?

And sorry, I will try to have a correct english.